# Intel XDK, Make an determinate URL open in Native Browser instead my APP InAppBrowser

Tags: android, html, cordova, intel-xdk

I have an intel XDK project that opens my website inside an app.
There is a button download there that I would that when the user click on it, he opens at the Native Bowser!

I tried CORDOVA Whittelist, but doesnt worked!

Its like an "Internal vs External" from native.io

```
var url = "https://www.microhitz.com/songs";

            //*********************************//

            openInAppBrowser(url);    
        }
```

I Wanna this url open in NATIVE BROWSER...

```
<access origin="http://youtubeplaylist-mp3.com/download/index/*"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [inAppBrowser documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen), especially the _system option.